# How to add a new script block to html for Gulp.js?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, gulp-concat

I am using a yeoman gulp web-app.

The generated index.html file has a couple of pre-made script concatenation blocks, such as:

```
 <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
 <!-- bower:js -->
  ... js files ...
 <!-- endbower -->
 <!-- endbuild -->
```

I would like to add my own block, as I have done in Grunt, to be conditional for IE8.  In Grunt, I added this:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/ie8.js -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/respondJs/src/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

which compiles to

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="scripts/ie8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

When I try to add a block like this to my Gulp index.html, the build task throws an error:

```
events.js:74
    throw TypeError('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');
          ^
```

Thoughts?

**Update:**
Here's the final usemin task:

```
gulp.task('usemin', function() {
 gulp.src('app/*.html')
  .pipe(usemin({
    css: [minifycss(), 'concat'],
    //html: [minifyhtml({empty: true})],
    js: [uglify({mangle: false}), rev()]
  }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

Also, as suggested, I wrapped the conditional comments *around* the usemin comments:

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <!-- build:js scripts/ie8.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/respondJs/dest/respond.min.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Just a guess: wrap `build:js` block with conditional comments i.e. other way round.

Comment: I tried that.  Even without the conditional comments altogether.  Throws same error.

Comment: Have you installed those bower components that go to `ie8.js`?

Comment: I get error only if I leave them uninstalled.

Comment: that did work, thanks.  i think when i tried last time i was having a bower_components path problem.

Comment: Hi @Steve, I would like to know how you implemented your Gulp config. can you share it? (just the task will be helpful)

Comment: Added it to the question above.  Let me know if you need more.